# Contenteditable reset text color after foreColor has been used without resetting other styles

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Changing the text color of text in a contenteditable div is easy - simply called `document.execCommand("foreColor",false,"#FFF")` to change text color to white.

However, I cannot find a way to reset this color back to its default value (or to the value of the parent element). `document.execCommand("removeFormat",false,null)` works perfectly, except that it will also remove any bold or italic styles, which is not what I want. Simply setting the color to black works, apart from if you have a link in the selection (which should stay the same color).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm having success with the following:

```
document.execCommand("removeFormat", false, "foreColor");
```

Seems (so far) that `removeFormat` can be understood to remove only formatting created by a particular command.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about that. Which browsers does it work in?

Comment: I've had it work as expected on Internet Explorer 7-9, Chrome, and Firefox. Sadly my machine has had trouble of late with Safari and Opera so I'm not able to verify it on those platforms.

Comment: If you throw it into a jsfiddle, I'd be happy to test it on Opera and Safari.

Comment: It doesn't work me unfortunately (Chrome 30) - it deletes all formatting whatsoever. However, there's an interesting drawback: calling a command `foreColor` with `black` as an argument deletes all `font` tags by default. Maybe because of default CSS rules? Don't know. But it works.

Comment: Still does not work in Chrome, unfortunately (deletes all formatting instead)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a partial answer, but I'm still looking for a solution for Chrome:

In IE9, you can use the following:

```
document.execCommand("foreColor",false,"")
```

In Firefox, you can use this:

```
document.execCommand("foreColor",false,"inherit")
```

But in Chrome, passing null/empty string does nothing, while passing 'inherit' results in setting the text color to "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" -- transparent black.  Clearly this is a bug.  I would love to see a more reliable cross-browser way to do this.