# Weird result from execCommand with foreColor command

Tags: css, google-chrome, contenteditable, execcommand

http://jsfiddle.net/dD2pE/2/

Press 'inherit' button on above test page.

After running `foreColor` command with `inherit` to `color` via `execCommand`, it displays as weird color - #BA0000. (Tested in Chrome 30)
It looks like Chrome tried to set text color with `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` but it was parsed with last six characters - 'b, a, 0, 0, 0, 0'. So it turned to #BA0000.

But `inherit` on `backColor` command works very well as intended.

Is this a bug of Chrome? or is it prohibited using `inherit` on `foreColor` command?

---

Added)

I'm just using `styleWithCSS` instead of handling `<font color>` stuff.
After applying `styleWithCSS`, formatting command uses css properties with `<span>` element instead `<font>`.

Answer (score 0):

see [duplicated question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842942/contenteditable-reset-text-color-after-forecolor-has-been-used-without-resetting/13654399)

execCommand() generate deprecated tags like `<font>`. avoid to use it if possible.

Comment: Slightly different question. And also `execCommand("removeFormat", null, "foreColor")` does not work properly on Chrome 30, Firefox 23 - it removes entire formatting. See http://jsfiddle.net/dD2pE/5/ .